# How can I limit the number of returned results to only the 1000 latest entries with Flask / SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, caching, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm looking for something similar to how reddit/hackernews specifically (this seems a common approach by a lot of major sites) handle their 'new' listing. It appears to work like so:

- when a new link is submitted, a certain number of the latest entries is grabbed
- those queries are divided up by a PER_PAGE # and cached as cachekey = newestPage1,2,3,4
- clicking the next/previous buttons loads the next/prev cachekey

My problem is: its difficult to find SQLalchemy/flask-sqlalchemy code for getting a query of only a fixed # of the latest entries.

how do I say:

```
q = PostDB.query(order_by('creation_time').desc()).limit(1000)
for chunkOf50Results in q:
  cache.set(CachedChunk+=1, chunkOf50Results)
```

?

Answer (score 4):

If you slice a query in SQLAlchemy, it automatically limits the database result set fetched:

```
limitedQuery = q[:50]
```

If you were to get a count first, you can easily loop over chunked responses:

```
count = q.count()
for chunkstart in xrange(0, count, 50):
    CachedChunk += 1
    chunkend = min(chunkstart + 50, count)
    cache.set(CachedChunk, q[chunstart:chunkend])
```

Note that this does result in multiple queries to the database. Alternatively you can use a the [`itertools.izip_longest()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to produce groups of 50 items:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for chunkOf50Results in izip(*[q.yield_per(50)]*50):
     CachedChunk += 1
     cache.set(CachedChunk, chunkOf50Results)
```

I used [`.yield_per(50)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per) to limit row pre-fetching to the batchsize so you don't pre-fetch more than you need per batch.

The `izip_longest(*[iterable]*n)` trick gives you groups of size `n` out of a base iterator:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(range(7))]*3))
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, None, None)]
```

Note that the last batch is padded with `None` values to fill out to the batch size.

Comment: can't wait to try this out. if this is run everytime a new entry is posted (to update the chunks), won't q.count()'ing every time become a huge operation when there are millions of rows to count?

Comment: @chrickso: Databases *should* optimize that case. A row count should be cheap (enough).

Comment: sadly this is not always the case, depending on the database in use.  MySQL in particular is notorious for scanning the entire table every time count() is called in some cases.    There are other pagination schemes that don't depend on "count", but these obviously can't give you the total number of pages available.

Comment: @zzzeek: I am leaning more and more towards the `izip_longest` method in any case. :-) Thanks for the MySQL scan case, I'm happy to say I usually do not need to use that database.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with a trick [described in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

```
q = PostDB.query(order_by('creation_time').desc()).limit(1000)

query_iterators = [iter(q)] * 50

for CachedChunk, chunk_of_50 in enumerate(izip_longest(*query_iterators)):
     cache.set(CachedChunk, chunk_of_50)
```

This *should* result in **one** trip to the database fetching up to 1000 articles and then letting you split them up into batches of 50 and cache them.

Comment: how do i ensure that the 1000 fetched are the latest entries and not some random batch it gathered until it reached 1000?

Comment: well, i'm trying to understand the order of operations here. when i do q = PostDB.query(order_by('creation_time').desc()).limit(1000), i would think that will go get the first 1000 rows and then sort them by creation_time, not ensuring those 1000 are the latest 1000

Comment: @chrickso - nope, it sorts the entire table by creation time (from newest to oldest) and then takes the first 1000 off the list.  (Actually most DBs are quite a bit smarter than that and will use indexes if available to avoid having to sort everything).